# How to align widgets in Tkinter to center

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am working on a simple counter app in tkinter. I rigged up some code looking at few tutorial on web. All the functions of a counter are set up. But when it comes to the designing of the app, I want the Count, the Count button, and the reset button to be aligned at the center.

The code is as below

```
from tkinter import Label, Button, Tk
from tkinter import font


window = Tk()

window.geometry('500x500')

window.title("Counter")

window.count = 0

def increment():
    window.count += 1
    lbl.configure(text=window.count)


def reset():
    window.count = 0
    lbl.configure(text=window.count)


lbl = Label(window, text="0", font=("Apple Braille", 60))
lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)

btn1 = Button(window, text="Count", command=increment)
btn1.grid(column=0, row=1)

btn2 = Button(window, text="Reset", command=reset)
btn2.grid(column=1, row=1)

btn1['font'] = btn2['font'] = font.Font(size=30)

window.mainloop()
```

A Screenshot of my counter app is here

[image: Tkinter Count app screenshot]

Any help in this aspect will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: This one was a general question on the ways of using pack instead of grid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easier to use `pack()` instead of `grid()` for your requirement.

```py
lbl = Label(window, text="0", font=("Apple Braille", 60))
lbl.pack()

# frame for the two buttons
frame = Frame(window)
frame.pack()

btn1 = Button(frame, text="Count", command=increment)
btn1.grid(column=0, row=1)

btn2 = Button(frame, text="Reset", command=reset)
btn2.grid(column=1, row=1)
```

---

If you want to put at the center of the window:

```py
# frame for the label and buttons
frame = Frame(window)
frame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor="c") # put at center of window

lbl = Label(frame, text="0", font=("Apple Braille", 60))
lbl.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2)

btn1 = Button(frame, text="Count", command=increment)
btn1.grid(column=0, row=1)

btn2 = Button(frame, text="Reset", command=reset)
btn2.grid(column=1, row=1)
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, it definitely solved the problem. Now everything is coming in top center. Can you make it at exact center?

Comment: @AdithiyaaAS Answer updated with example to put at the center of window.